# VirtualEnv TensorFlow installation validation with "ImportError: No module named tensorflow" when running pythonw

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, virtualenv

I installed TensorFlow on a virtual environment using the steps provided from the TensorFlow installation page for Mac OS X:

```
$ sudo easy_install pip
$ sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv
$ virtualenv --system-site-packages ~/tensorflow
$ source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate
(tensorflow)$ pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

When I try to verify that tensorflow was succesfully installed, I get an import error:

```
(tensorflow)$ pythonw
Python 2.7.13 (default, Mar  3 2017, 20:38:41)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

I double checked by executing `pip list`, and it shows that `tensorflow (1.1.0)` was indeed installed. My system is running on macOS Sierra.

Comment: What do `sys.path` and the `site-packages` directory under `~/tensorflow/lib` show?

Comment: Oh, yes, and is there a `pythonw` under `~/tensorflow/bin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activating `virtualenv` only redirects commands that exist under `<virtualenv_root>/bin`. `pythonw` is not among them, you need to invoke `python` instead. [A stub for `pythonw` is only created in Windows and Cygwin](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/master/virtualenv.py#L1234).

Comment: thanks! calling `python` instead of `pythonw` fixes the problem.